# Show textfield data and also change value in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textfield

I have this in my database

```
<input type="text" value="<%= account["accountname"] %>"/>
```

this will show the value of accountname in the field that I desire it too.

However, if I want the user to change that value to something else it doesn't allow that to occur.

If I put this in place of the above code sample

```
<%= text_field_tag :accountname, params[:accoutname] %>
```

This allows me to change the value and updates the database.  However, the field stays blank in the views to the user.

I am wondering if there is a way for me to be able to change the database as well as display the accountname in the views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name= "accountname" value="<%= account["accountname"] %>"/>
```

I needed to add the name field to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Did you cut-and-paste this code?  If so, you have a typo.

```
params[:accoutname]
```

:accountname

Comment: hey thanks for pointing that out.  I didn't copy and paste so luckily that wasn't the mistake.  I figured out how to solve my problem.

I needed to <input type="text" name= "accountname" value="<%= account["accountname"] %>"/>

I basically need to add the name field so it works now.